# php remove the leftmost number in string

Tags: php

For some reason, I want to remove the leftmost number inside the whole string.
Here are the example:

- 0abc > abc
- 23abc > abc
- 123abc456 > abc456
- 123ab1ab123 >  ab1ab123
- 99abc1a1a4 > abc1a1a4

Is it possible do in php?

I tried to use:

```
$words = preg_replace('/[0-9]+[a-z]/', '', $file);
```

but it will remove both the number and the first alphabet.

Answer (score 4):

You can just use an anchor and remove the `[a-z]` part from your regex:

```
$words = preg_replace('/^[0-9]+/', '', $file);
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  Found that I can do it with
$words = preg_replace('/(^\d+)/', '', $file);

Comment: @HuangLun Yes, but that capturing group won't change much :)

Comment: its hard not to be able to write multiple regular expressions for an circumstances given its flexibility

Answer (score 2):

and if you dont like Rizier123 aswer:

```
$words = ltrim('123ab1ab123','0123456789');
```

or

```
$words = ltrim('123ab1ab123','0..9');
```

trims all numbers from left, probably faster than are regular expression also

Comment: You want to say, that you don't like my answer? ಥ_ಥ

Comment: well i did say **IF** :-) @Rizier123